# Setting a data binding on a UI control created programmatically in a Windows 8 C++/Xaml app

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, visual-c++, windows-8, microsoft-metro

As per [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh758320.aspx) and several other references, the way to create a data binding with Xaml/C++ in Windows 8 is to do the following:

In C++:

- Create a bindable class,
- Set the DataContext property to an instance of that class.

In Xaml:

```
<Object AnyProperty="{Binding Path=AnotherProperty, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

How would I achieve that binding if I constructed `Object` through C++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this page be of any help to you?

[How to: Create a Binding in Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742863%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

The example on the page seems to use a SetBinding instance method on a textblock to bind a property to the text property of the textblock. Maybe there is a similar method in C++?